# C++ cannot figure out how to jump into the switch from user input

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, do-while

ok so i am writing a console application that uses a switch to display products and prices. however i am having hell figuring out how to make it jump into the switch when the user inputs the product number

this is the code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int productNum = 0;  
int quantityArray[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
quantityArray[i] = 0;
char answer = ('y' || 'n' || 'e' || 'Y' || 'N' || 'E');
double priceArray[5] = { 2.98, 4.50, 9.98, 4.99, 6.87 };
double total1 = (quantityArray[0] * priceArray[0]);
double total2 = (quantityArray[1] * priceArray[1]);
double total3 = (quantityArray[2] * priceArray[2]);
double total4 = (quantityArray[3] * priceArray[3]);
double total5 = (quantityArray[4] * priceArray[4]);
double checkout = total1 + total2 + total3 + total4 + total5;

cout << "Please select a product number 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5" << endl;
cin >> productNum;
do
    {

       switch (productNum)
       {
       case '1':
           cout << "1 inch x 1 inch sticker is $" << priceArray[0] << endl;
       cout << "How many of these stickers would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cin >> quantityArray[0];
              cout << "You have selected " << quantityArray[0] << "at the price of $" << priceArray[0] << endl;
              cout << "Is this correct?" << endl;
              cout << "Y for yes, N for no, E to checkout." << endl;
              cin >> answer;
       case '2':
              cout << "3 inch x 2 inch sticker is $" << priceArray[1] << endl;
              cout << "How many of these stickers would you like to purchase?" << endl;
              cin >> quantityArray[1];
              cout << "You have selected " << quantityArray[1] << "at the price of $" << priceArray[1] << endl;
              cout << "Is this correct?" << endl;
              cout << "Y for yes, N for no, E to checkout." << endl;
              cin >> answer;
       case '3':
              cout << "7 inch x 7 inch sticker is $" << priceArray[2] << endl;
              cout << "How many of these stickers would you like to purchase?" << endl;
              cin >> quantityArray[2];
              cout << "You have selected " << quantityArray[2] << "at the price of $" << priceArray[2] << endl;
              cout << "Is this correct?" << endl;
              cout << "Y for yes, N for no, E to checkout." << endl;
              cin >> answer;
       case '4':
              cout << "3 inch x 3 inch sticker is our current special at $" << priceArray[3] << endl;
              cout << "How many of these stickers would you like to purchase?" << endl;
              cin >> quantityArray[3];
              cout << "You have selected " << quantityArray[3] << "at the price of $" << priceArray[3] << endl;
              cout << "Is this correct?" << endl;
              cout << "Y for yes, N for no, E to checkout." << endl;
              cin >> answer;
       case '5':
              cout << "5 inch x 4 inch sticker is $" << priceArray[4] << endl;
              cout << "How many of these stickers would you like to purchase?" << endl;
              cin >> quantityArray[4];
              cout << "You have selected " << quantityArray[4] << "at the price of $" << priceArray[4] << endl;
              cout << "Is this correct?" << endl;
              cout << "Y for yes, N for no, E to checkout." << endl;
              cin >> answer;
                if (answer = 'y' || 'Y')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (answer = 'n' || 'N')
                {
                    cout << "Please select a qantity." << endl;
                }
                else if (answer = 'e' || 'E')
                {
                    cout << checkout << endl;
                }
       }
    }while (answer != 'e' || 'E');
```

}

my book uses a header file to show how to initialize a swtich but it uses multiple methods. I am pretty sure that I can get this into one method without using a header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you read the input as an integer, but the cases are on character.

For example, the *character* `'1'` is (on the vast majority of computers) the same as the *integer* `49`.

change the cases to the integers instead:

```
case 1:
    // ...

case 2:
    // ...
```

etc.

Comment: thank you that makes alot of sense i think i got lost since ive been working on this for four hours now

Answer (score 2):

Your switch statements are "wrong" because you read an integer then compare it with characters, which doesn't mean the same thing. You should also have a `break;` at the end of each `case` unless you actually WANT to fall through to the next case.

Code like this:

```
 (answer = 'y' || 'Y')
```

can be rewritten as this (to clarify what it does):

```
 ((answer = 'y') || 'Y')
```

It is wrong in two ways: First `answer = 'y'` sets the variable `answer` to `'y'` (and it turns the statement to 'true' because the value of the whole expression is `'y'` which is compared with zero (which would make it false) - it is not zero, so the statement ends there and executes what is inside the if. You should use the "is equal to" operator `==`, rather than "assignment operator" `=` to check if something is matching. If you fix that, and `answer == 'y'` isnt' true, the second part `|| 'Y'` doesn't do at all what you want, but rather checks if `'Y'` is zero or not (and it is not).

To fix this, you need to use `if (answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y')` and similar.

Same applies to this `char answer = ('y' || 'n' || 'e' || 'Y' || 'N' || 'E');`, it sets answer to `true` [or `1`], because the logical or of the values is not zero - and only `'y'` gets checked, because C and C++ is defined to "stop checking once we've found something that determines the whole sequence".

I have two suggestions:
 1. Only write a LITTLE bit of code at a time. Test that it works before you continue with the next step. }
 2. Enable warnings in your compiler. Compile often. This will help you detect and fix problems before you written a lot of code that is "wrong".

Comment: yeah i started off doing that but then i got confused so i went and wrote a bunch of psudocode to help my organize my thoughts. i got over zealous. thank you for the pointers. i enjoy c++ a lot anything that helps me is appreciated